# How to return any one row among all the rows with a matching attribute in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, amazon-dynamodb

I have many rows with a common attribute in my table and there are many such groups. Given an attribute, how to return any row among the group?
Is there any built-in thing to choose any one among all? Or something that returns a row based on first occurrence kind of?

Answer (score 0):

You can run:

```
select <field list> from some_table where <your conditions> order by rand() limit 1
```

This will return only one random row.

For first occurance (which ever it could be) remove `order by rand()`